# how to debug Tornado async operation

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I am new to Tornado framework, and according to the link [Asynchronous and non-Blocking I/O](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/async.html), I wrote some demo code as below. Unfortunately, the sync http client works, but async http client not. It looks like, the callback function that I passed to AsyncHTTPClient.fetch never has the chance to run. So my question is:

- Why tornado's async API not work for me?
- How should I debug this kind of problem? Set a break-point to my callback function is useless because it never has chance to run.

Any help is great appreciated. Below is my demo code:

```
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
from tornado.httpclient import HTTPClient
import time

myUrl = 'a http url serving RESTful service'


def async_fetch(url, callback):
    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    def handle_test(response):
        callback(response.body)
    http_client.fetch(url, handle_test)


def sync_fetch(url):
    http_client = HTTPClient()
    response = http_client.fetch(url)
    return response.body


def printResponse(data):
    print("response is:" + data)


def main():
    sync_fetch(myUrl)   #this works
    async_fetch(myUrl, printResponse)  #this not work


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    print("begin of sleep!")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("end of sleep!")
```

Comment: If you want asynchronous behavior, you need to start an ioloop instance which handles the asynchronous io. So you need to have a line such that: `tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start the IOLoop, otherwise your asynchronous task never makes progress:

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

def printResponse(data):
    print("response is:" + data)
    IOLoop.current().stop()


def main():
    sync_fetch(myUrl)   #this works
    async_fetch(myUrl, printResponse)
    IOLoop.current().start()
```

In this example I stop the loop at the bottom of printResponse. In a real web server application you might *never* explicitly stop the loop.

Comment: Thanks very much, this works for me !

one little change is , tornado.io_loop has been renamed to tornado.ioloop.

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected my code. Is there anything else I can help you with, or will you accept my answer as correct on Stack Overflow?